# Is application written from scratch in programming language has to be license?

Tags: programming-languages, licensing

There are so many programming language like PHP, Perl, Python, Java, C, C++ and many other. These programming language has some open source license.
If i develop application from scratch which is not related the source modification of these languages. Is my application has to be open source license??
There are billions of applications written in these language? All application has be open source? I don't understand that, is there language issue ever existed? I think there should not programming language  licensing issue just like spoken language..either i speak in english, french or any other. I can write a book in any language without my book to be open source, is that right???

Comment: You need to reduce your coffee consumption by about 50 percent.  As to your question, generally speaking, you can license your applications any way you want, regardless of the compiler/interpreter license (there wouldn't be much point, otherwise).

Comment: Of course it could be a point of having a compiler/standard library with a license that doesn't allow for closed source software. Just as there is software distributions out there that contains only open source software (like debian).

Comment: Most *languages* don't have licences. Most *implementations* of languages do. In many cases (C and C++, for example), there's a license for the language standard document, but that doesn't apply to the language itself.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_programming_languages you can check the wiki, you will find the license for each programming language. For GPL programming language, is my project has to be GPL or not. That is my question? Please try to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this depends on the laws in your country. Generally speaking though, you own your sourcecode. However a license on a programming language can make your sourcecode useless on its own. (at least if some part of the programming language is patented and you live in a part of the world with software patents).

However more realistic is that some standard library or the compiler is protected. For example if you write a C-program and link that to glibc and we assume that glibc is under GPL, your program has to be GPL compatible if your release it (note that glibc is under LGPL and *not* GPL so this doesn't apply).

Generally the licenses of standard libraries and compilers does not force your application to be open source.

What I know, none of the languages your mentioned has any license at all, their compilers do, and a few of them has plenty of compilers...

Comment: There's a lot of hand-waving, but I don't see much of an answer here.  Perhaps if you rewrote your answer to be more specific and have better focus.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_programming_languages you can check the wiki, you will find the license for each programming language.

Comment: @padamgurung that's a list of the licenses for the implementations, not for the languages...

Comment: @iveqy .. please make me clear what is mean by implementations license? If you could, then clarify with example.

Comment: @padamgurung take C# as an example. It has the microsoft .NET implementation that is closed source and Mono ( http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page ) that is an open source implementation of C#.

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages, or rather the compilers and interpreters that process programs written in those languages, almost never force a license on the programs you write with them.  So you can use a Free Software C compiler like `gcc` and compiler proprietary, closed-source programs. What you cannot do is incorporate Free Software or Open Source code in your closed-source program, and that may be harder than you expect.  For example, the output of `gcc` is usually linked against one of a few implementations of the C Standard Library, all of which are Free Software or Open Source.  And without some of that code, except in some very specific environments, your program cannot run.

Comment: A notable (and fairly uncommon) exception is (was?) Opa, which, becuase its standard library was licensed AGPL, it imposed the AGPL on all applications.

Comment: The C Standard Library is not GPL, is it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would depend on what implementation of the C library we're talking about.  Some are LGPL, some are BSD, some aren't open source.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that this really shouldn't be a consideration for a C standard library, and if it is, I'm not going to use it anyway.  Doesn't matter, the question is hopeless.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_programming_languages you can check the wiki, you will find the license for each programming language

Comment: @padamgurung Nope.  What you'll find there are the licenses for certain specific implementations of those languages.  And they differ.  For example, there are 9 Scheme implementations with 5 different licenses.  But Scheme itself is not covered by a license.